# Python 3: Comparing two elements of the same list

Tags: python-3.x

I'd like to compare one element of the list after another. I achieved my goal but it's not a well-written code. Please look at my code and give my a some advices. By the way I have a few other questions

```
players_list = ( {'player_name': 'Tom',
                 'player_flag': 'is_human',
                 'player_decision': None,
                 'player_points': 1}

                {'player_name': 'Peter',
                 'player_flag': 'is_computer',
                 'player_decision': None,
                 'player_points': 2}

                 {'player_name': 'John',
                 'player_flag': 'is_computer',
                 'player_decision': None,
                 'player_points': 0.5}

                 {'player_name': 'Greg',
                 'player_flag': 'is_computer',
                 'player_decision': None,
                 'player_points': 2} 
                )

players_list  = sorted(players_list, key = lambda k: k['player_points'], reverse =  True)) #(1)

iterator = 0 #(2)
while players_list[iterator]['player_points'] == players_list[iterator + 1]['player_points']: 
    iterator += 1

print('   >> The Winner Is...', end = ' ')
if iterator == 0:
    print(players_list[0]['player_name'].upper(), '!!!') #(3)
elif iterator > 0:
    print('There Is a Draw Between ', end = '')
    for j in range (0, iterator + 1):
        print(players_list[j]['player_name'], end = ', ') # (4))

    print() # (5)
```

(1): Is it the best way in this case to sort my list by values of dictionaries?

(2): It is my idea to compare to solve the problem. Could you give your opinion and- if it is needed - propose better solution, please?

(3): What way of printing in this case would be the most 'pythonic'?

```
print(players_list[0]['player_name'].upper(), '!!!') # 1    
print(%s!!! (players_list[0]['player_name'].upper())) # 2
print({player_name}!!!.format(player_name = players_list[0] ['player_name']).upper()) # 3
```

(4): How to display list of players in one line without the ',' at the end?

```
print(players_list[j]['player_name'], end = ', ')
>> Peter, Greg, Tom, John,
```

(5) I used an empty print() to display '/n' after displaying players in one line. Is there a better solution?

Many thanks

Comment: This would be better suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm going to do it when I will have all code ready. It is the last one issue which I know that I should correct

Comment: The empty `print()` ? It's not an issue, it's a perfectly valid code. I'm not sure you'll find a better way to print an empty line.

Comment: @tmoreau: I mean something like that: `print(players_list[j]["player_name"], end = ",", the_final_end = "\n")`. Of course I know that this form does not exist, that's just an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fails when all players have the same number of points.

In any case, you do not need, nor want, to sort the list. You want to scan it, looking for the element(s) with the maximum number of points.

Untested code:

```
winners = None
winner_points = None
for p in players_list:
    points = p['player_points']
    if winner_points is None or winner_points < points:
        winners = [p]
        winner_points = points
    elif winner_points == points:
        winners.append(p)

if not winners:
    print("Nobody played today!")
elif len(winners) == 1:
    print("The winner is", winners[0]['player_name'])
else:
    print("There is a draw between %d players: %s" % (len(winners), ", ".join(p['player_name'] for p in winners))
```

Also, coding style:

- don't store the data for each player in a hash. That's what objects are for.
- don't name the fields `player_XXX`. `player['XXX']` is much more readable. Using objects, i.e. `player.XXX`, even more so.

Comment: I didn't noticed that my code fails there. Anyway I thought to create a new list and placed inside it the winners but I had not idea how to do it properly. I admit I had not thought about scan the list, looking for the elements with the highest number of points. Many thanks for good solution.